# Is it able to get all Java classes is called in runtime?

Tags: java, jvm

After finishing my project, I want to remove all the unused classes to reduce the size of jar file when packaging.

I am using IntelliJ, it can help me detect unused classed but it includes some classes are only called by reflection (runtime only). Moreover, it cannot detect unused classes in external libraries.

One important thing, I want to remove unused classed in external libraries. Example, when I use BiMap from Google Guava, I have to include Guava lib, but I just want to use only BiMap, including whole Guava makes my jar getting big

So, I thinked reversely, instead of finding unused classes, I want to know all the classes is used/called when run (I will remove unused classed/packages manually). How can I do that?

Comment: Why don't you check for where the class are referenced in your project. If the class is never used, delete it? #JustAThought.

Comment: @Buhake Sindi: not only my project, I want to remove unused classes in external lib, too. Example when I use BiMap from Google Guava, I have to include Guava lib, but I just want to use only BiMap, including whole Guava makes my jar getting big

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a tool like Proguard (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to do this

Comment: I thinked Proguard cannot work with external lib, and also reflection

Comment: Proguard can build a uber-jar with all used classes from libraries, and remove unused classes. For keeping a class used by reflection, you must adjust proguard configuration to force to keep this class

Comment: But how can I know which classes are used by reflection?

Comment: You need to have this information. Either it is your own source code and you obviously know which classes are loaded dynamically, either you should read the documentation of the library... not sure they give us this information. You can also found these classes in practice by starting your application and log all classes loaded at the moment, but you can miss some. I see no other way to do what you want

Comment: "you can miss some", I have test cases, I will run all them, so I cannot miss.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure how you can limit the contents of the jar file to only the referenced Java classes. You may also run into issues when a class is loaded dynamically.

Guava explains on their site how you can include a subset of Guava in your build, by using ProGuard: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava

Comment: to limit, just open & delete .class files by WinRar. "You may also run into issues when a class is loaded dynamically", it is my concern, so I want to know exactly which classes is used in runtime. Btw, Guava is just my example

Comment: While deleting .class files manually in the archive will work, I think it is a very timeconsuming and error prone process. Typically you want to automate your build and package process as much as possible. This will free your time to do real coding, and reduce the chance of build errors.

Comment: obviously, I will write script to do it automatically. I Just give the solution